# Possibly sent Bitcoin to wrong address

Tags: transactions, coinbase.com

Almost a week ago I sent .05 BTC from my coinbase account to what I thought was my jaxx address, but I haven't received it.

The transaction ([here](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/1JERLfTG41p59o4FRHGfD3c3Jd2jg4z7FY/)) says that some of the output of the transaction was spent. Does that mean that I sent my BTC to the wrong address and the receiver spent it?

Comment: What receiving address does your Jaxx wallet show? Is it 1JERLfTG41p59o4FRHGfD3c3Jd2jg4z7FY ? It looks like the 1LWRFR6c7Huz6D44yKwMXPfxqQdeuH5orm address that had 0.41.. btc sent to it (now spent) was Coinbase's change address for your transaction. The 0.05 btc sent is confirmed and still unspent.

Comment: It shows an address starting with 1Hnep... I'm not sure where I got the 1JERL... from. Did I just send it to the wrong address and lose it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have sent your bitcoin to the wrong address, if that is the case it is likely gone. The 0.05 btc is sitting in address 1JERLf..., and has not moved since the coinbase withdrawl. If you control that address then there is no issue

You can try 'reset Jaxx cache', the wallet software might be experiencing some sort of bug and not displaying your balance correctly.

It may be worth checking any other wallet software you have, to see if you sent the btc to that wallet instead of Jaxx, and got mixed up about which wallet you got the receiving address from.